# Добавить пункт область для меню в WP?

Tags: wordpress

Как добавить область для меню при создании / измнении темы для ВП? 
чтобы именно в админке были области для меню доступные. https://truemisha.ru/images/2014/07/wordpress-menu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `function.php`

```
function theme_register_nav_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_register_nav_menu' );
```

Comment: не понял как  прикрутить теперь в нужном месте в коде страницы ту точку в которой хочу вывести меню )

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос. Только сформулируйте его как-то. Из сказанного ничего не понятно.

Comment: Если один из предложенных ответов устраивает, его стоит отметить как принятый

Comment: я зарегал primary. Теперь в файле шаблона нужно добавить $args = array(
 'theme_location' => 'primary'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args );  получается?

Comment: Да. Вот реальный код с одного из моих сайтов:

wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location' => 'top',
  'menu_id'        => 'top-menu',
 ) );

Answer (score 1):

Это делается с пом функции `wp_nav_menu`
см
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/
https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Это вывод на экран, а он про регистрацию меню спрашивает, чтобы в админке были области.

Comment: "Как добавить область".. куда , если не в шаблон темы? Впрочем, ориентиры даны, есть откуда плясать. А то так надо начать с `add_theme_support` и про `register_nav_menus` не забыть ;)

Comment: А самое смешное (или печальное), что [источник скриношота](https://truemisha.ru/blog/wordpress/nav-menu-walkers.html) об этом всём рассказывает.

Comment: скриншот с гугл картинок брал, не проверял источник

Comment: по той статье вообще без особых обьяснений тот пункт проходят

Comment: зато как в админке меню создать на 7 абзацев разжовано )

Comment: так что не помогла

Comment: Если почитать, то поможет. Там всё разжевано и пр  этом без воды (волкер не нужно, это след этап, и про стили отдельная песня. а остальное всё что нужно). И по ссылке, что я дал в ответе тоже.

Comment: Как обозначить область для вывода меню в шаблоне он ничего не пишет там, просто дает этот код $args = array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ); wp_nav_menu( $args );                                                                                                            -  и мне он не особо понятен, В остальном хорошо написано - не спорю.